# C++ XOR decryption giving out the lengh of the key

Tags: c++, encryption, xor

I am writing a short password saving program for school. Everythign works fine, I can encrypt the passwords with a string key but as soon as I decrypt them with the same function, I only get the right password but only the lengh of the key as output. The encrypted passwords in my data base still have the same lengh as the cleartext password.

This is the function that I use to en- and decrypt my passwords.

```
string enDecryption(string password, string key)
{
    string xorStr = "";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
    {
        xorStr.push_back(password[i] ^ key[i % key.length()]);
    }

    return xorStr;

}
```

Comment: and what did you see when you stepped through the code with your debugger?

Comment: That code inserts the same number of characters into `xorStr` as it finds in `password`. So surely it's working as intended? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Works fine for me, see it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76905076deda7219).

Comment: @Tommy No, it's supposed to be a [Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher), the OP is wrapping the key around.

Comment: I misread the question; I took the complaint to be that encoded passwords are the same length as decoded passwords. Which they are, in the database, but which is not the problem. Disregard me. Thanks, @vsoftco!